# Semaphore and mutex loop

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

I have two functions that I use semaphore and mutex for a variant of classic the sleeping barber problem. But when I run the program, the program never ends.

Function 1: the actions of TA (barber for barber example)

```
void *teaching_assistant()
{       
        printf("\t<-- TA opened his office\n");
        printf("\t<-- TA waiting for student\n");
        
        while(1){
                // If there is waiting students
                if(waiting_students > 0){
                        ta_sleep_flag = 0;
                        sem_wait(&sem_stu);
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

                        // TA giving advice to student
                        printf("\t<-- TA starts advising session\n");

                        num_chairs[next_teaching_position] = 0;
                        waiting_students--;
                        next_teaching_position = (next_teaching_position + 1) % NUM_MAX_CHAIR;

                        sleep(adviceperiod);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
                        sem_post(&sem_ta);
                }
                // If there is no waiting student
                else{
                        if(ta_sleep_flag == 0){
                                printf("\t<-- TA finished advising, taking a short nap\n");
                                ta_sleep_flag = 1;
                                sleep(napperiod);
                                sem_post(&sem_ta);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Function 2: the actions of student (customer for barber example)

```
void *student(void *student_id)
{
        int id_student = (int *)student_id;
        printf("std<%d> entered lab\n", id_student);

        while(1){
                // If there is a waiting student, continue waiting
                if(waiting_status(id_student) == 1){ continue; }

                // Student is programming
                printf("std<%d> programming for %d units\n", id_student, workperiod);
                sleep(workperiod);

                pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
                
                printf("std<%d> checking TA office\n", id_student);
                //found available cahir 
                if(waiting_students < NUM_MAX_CHAIR){
                        num_chairs[next_seating_position] = id_student;
                        waiting_students++;
                        chair++;
                        printf("std<%d> entered TA office; %d seats occupied\n", id_student, chair);
                        next_seating_position = (next_seating_position + 1) % NUM_MAX_CHAIR;

                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

                        // Wake TA if sleeping
                        sem_post(&sem_stu);
                        sem_wait(&sem_ta);
                }
                
                // Go drink coffe if there is no available seat
                else{
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
                        sleep(coffeeperiod);
                        sem_post(&sem_stu);
                }
        }
}
```

My expected output is:

```
<--TA opened his office
<--TA waiting for a student
std <2145236736> entered lab 
std <2145236736>programming for 10 units
std <2145236736> checking TA office
std <2145236736> entered TA office; 1 seats occupied
<--TA starts advising session
std <2145236736> asking questions
std <2145236736> leaving TA office
std <2145236736> signing off; active students= 0
<--TA finished advising, taking a short nap
<--TA signing off
```

But when i compile the code I get endless loop.

Comment: *I get endless loop*. What does that mean exactly? Please show the output (or at least enough of it to show what is happening).

Comment: The issue you are having is both within your main, which you haven't posted, and within teaching_assistant function : you did not implement any means for the TA to know that there won't be any more students, the loop in the function is effectively infinite. Your main 1. launches teaching_assistant, 2. loops through launching N students, 4. then wait for all threads to terminate. You are lacking 3. somehow signal TA that he should close the shop, which can be done with a OPEN flag going from true to false, passed by pointer as parameter. (Not an answer : Can't be sure about it with given intel)